# Why is setNext in add (to front) method there?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am not able to understand why the `newNode.setNext` is there. If the first node is not empty, the `newNode` adds to the last previous item. Can someone explain this?

I just want someone to illustrate this algorithm a bit better

```
Node<ListType> first = null;

public void add(ListType data) {
   Node<ListType> newNode = new Node<ListType>(data);   
   if (first != null)
   {
       newNode.setNext(first);
       first = newNode;
       return;
   }
   first = newNode;
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about exactly what you're confused about?

Comment: Think about it this way. If the collection only stores a single node *first*, and a new node is inserted. unless we connect our new node to the existing node, how will we be able to access it later?

Comment: I suggest that you get a good old fashioned pencil and paper, and hand execute the code, using a boxes (with cells) for the Node objects and arrows to represent the references.  (Any good data structures book will have examples ...)

Comment: Note - If `setNext` is just a setter, you can call it even if the parameter is `null`, thus the if-statement may not be necessary (which would reduce the function to 3 lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is adding a new element to the front (head) of the list. To add `A` to the list `B, C, D`:

```
B → C → D
```

needs to become

```
A → B → C → D
```

The `if(first!=null)` check is checking that the list is not empty. If there are not elements in the list when `add()` is called, then we don't have any existing element to set the (new) `first`'s `next` to.

Comment: why is this linked list going in the opposite way?

Comment: most of the linked list i have seen go from left to right... this one goes from right to left
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html

Comment: No, the list in my answer also "goes from left to right," hence why I said that **the new element is added to the front of the list.** That's the entire point of what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Add is something your are inserting first element

```
Node<ListType> first=null;

public void addfirst(ListType data) {
  if(first==null) {
     first = new Node<ListType>(data);
  }
  else { 
     first = null;
     first = new Node<ListType>(data);
  }

}
```

for addafter you can do

```
public void addafter(ListType data) {

  if(first==null) {
     first = new Node<ListType>(data);
  }else {
     Node<ListType> temp = first;
     while(temp.getNext()!=null){
        temp = temp.getNext();
     }
     temp.setNext(new Node<ListType>(data));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is so to improve the efficiency of the LinkedList. If not so, it will have to travel to the end of the list to put the value.

Comment: It has nothing to do with efficiency. It's possible to add an element to the end of a linked list in constant time.